# clientRenewProhibited status on domains in GoDaddy

Tags: godaddy

We found that we have quite a number of domains with the "clientRenewProhibited" status on Whois and when we contacted GoDaddy, they said that domain is currently locked and no unauthorized changes can be made. Only us as the owner can make those changes to a domain name.

Does anybody know how this relates to the iCann description that suggests that renewal requests will be rejected?
[image]